# Fedora 34 external monitors not detected with USB-C dock

Tags: fedora, nvidia, multi-monitor, displayport, dock-station

I have a fairly fresh install of Fedora 34 that I use with a USB dock. The dock has been working great for data, power, audio, and usb for a month. I just added two monitors to the setup connected by DisplayPort and my laptop can't detect them.

HP Spectre x360 15 w/ GeForce GTX 1650 Ti 
Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock - 40A90090US 
Two Planar PZN2410

`inxi -G` returns

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 470.63.01 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 3840x2160 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.1.8
```

`xrandr -q` retuns

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  59.98    59.97* 

   *other resolutions removed for simplicty* 
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`lsusb` returns

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00c9 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 033: ID 17ef:3063 Lenovo ThinkPad Dock Audio
Bus 001 Device 032: ID 17ef:1021 Lenovo ThinkPad Dock Hub [Cypress HX2VL]
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 0403:6015 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd Bridge(I2C/SPI/UART/FIFO)
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 17ef:1026 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 17ef:3060 Lenovo ThinkPad Dock
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 17ef:3062 Lenovo ThinkPad Dock Ethernet [Realtek RTL8153B]
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 17ef:1025 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

DisplayLink drivers have been installed from https://github.com/displaylink-rpm/displaylink-rpm.

I'm new to linux. Every solution I've found online involved updating to drivers, modes, or kernels that I seem to already be using. Any advice on a how to get the monitors detected would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you solve this? I have a similar problem.